# Is it possible to rotate an object around an arbitrary origin using quaternions?

Tags: opengl-es, three.js, glsl

I'm wondering if it's possible to define an object's rotation not around itself but around an arbitrary origin, effectively removing the need to pass XYZ position vectors to the GPU.  So instead of having XYZ position + XYZW quaternion, we could pre-compute a quaternion that would solely define the object's position and rotation all by itself?

Comment: @WestLangley, why did you remove the OpenGL and GLSL tags?

Comment: Because the question is not about those topics.

Comment: I'm suprised and confused.  If it's not about GLSL or OpenGL, then why is it any more about three.js?

Comment: Fair question. I was assuming you are using three.js, and asking the question in that context. Apologies if that was not correct.

Comment: Sorry for the spamming, but the exact same question could be asked while using ANY OpenGL compatible abstraction layer, such as jMonkeyEngine in Java or GLUT in C++ or SharpGL in C#.  If I had to delete tags, I would have deleted three.js, the one which probably belongs the less in there, no? I mean, by cutting OpenGL and GLSL tags, you cancel out a lot of people NOT searching for threejs tag, but who could have seen this thread looking for OpenGL quaternions implementations.  Or am I missing something here? I'm sorry for being upset by this.

Comment: The tags are based on the content, not on the target audience. It actually makes more sense as a math question for another forum. In any event, since you are unhappy, I reverted the change.

Comment: LOL and 15 mins later, somebody else changed the tags again for OpenGL-ES, what the... But yes, it belongs to MATHS more than anything else and I should have put it there, actually.  Either way, convo closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible with a pure quaternion. A quaternion has only four degrees of freedom. If you use it for transformation, these will be three degrees for rotation and one degree for scaling. There is just nothing more a quaternion can offer.

[Dual Quaternions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_quaternion), however, can represent translations (and thus also rotations about arbitrary axes). This comes with the cost of four more numbers to store and usually it is not worth the trouble. The advantage of dual quaternions is that rigid body transforms can be expressed in a consolidated way with a nice algebraic background. It is usually used for animation to interpolate between multiple transforms in a consistent way.

In most cases, the advantages of dual quaternions do not outweigh their complexity. Hence, using a simple offset vector is more reasonable most of the time.

Comment: The goal was to reduce the number of vectors sent to the GPU in applications were there is a huge amount of them, so dual quaternions defeat the purpose I was thinking about.  Thanks for the clarifications.